# Does -[NSObject autoContentAccessingProxy] work at all?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make use of `-[NSObject autoContentAccessingProxy]` as described at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/autoContentAccessingProxy.

The object I am trying to proxy implements the `NSDiscardableContent` protocol and `-autoContentAccessingProxy` successfully returns a non-nil value.

If, however, I try to send a message to the proxy, I always get an `NSInvalidArgumentException` with a reason of "*** -[NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:] called!".

I understand that if I was writing my own `NSProxy`-based class, I would have to implement the `-methodSignatureForSelector:` method, but in this case, I am not writing the proxy, just trying to use the proxy provided by the documented method. For what it's worth, I can see that the proxy is actually of type `NSAutoContentAccessingProxy`, so I would expect that that class would indeed have an implementation for `-methodSignatureForSelector:`.

Here is a small block of code using an NSPurgeableData instance instead of my custom class. This small block has exactly the same issue.

```
NSPurgeableData * data = [NSPurgeableData dataWithBytes:"123" length:3];
NSLog(@"data.length = %u", data.length);
id proxyData = [data autoContentAccessingProxy];
NSLog(@"proxyData.length = %u", [proxyData length]);    //  throws NSInvalidArgumentException!
[data endContentAccess];
[data release];
```

Do I have some misunderstanding of the `-autoContentAccessingProxy` method here, or is it just completely broken?

Answer (score 11):

You can fix this bug by reimplementing what the `NSAutoContentAccessingProxy` class does but without the bugs. I have written such a class: `XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy`. The `autoContentAccessingProxy` method is replaced before your `main` function is called; this happens in the `+load` method. So all you have to do is compile the following code in your application and `autoContentAccessingProxy` will behave as expected.

Note that unlike my previous answer, you can actually use this solution in a shipping application.

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This code must be compiled with Automatic Reference Counting (CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC / -fobjc-arc)
#endif


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@interface XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy : NSProxy

+ (XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy *) proxyWithTarget:(id)target;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id target;

@end


@implementation XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy

@synthesize target = _target;

static id autoContentAccessingProxy(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return [XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy proxyWithTarget:self];
}

+ (void) load
{
    method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], @selector(autoContentAccessingProxy)), (IMP)autoContentAccessingProxy);
}

+ (XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy *) proxyWithTarget:(id)target
{
    if (![target conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSDiscardableContent)])
        return nil;

    if (![target beginContentAccess])
        return nil;

    XCDAutoContentAccessingProxy *proxy = [self alloc];
    proxy.target = target;
    return proxy;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self.target endContentAccess];
}

- (void) finalize
{
    [self.target endContentAccess];

    [super finalize];
}

- (id) forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return self.target;
}

- (NSMethodSignature *) methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [self.target methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}

- (void) forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    [invocation setTarget:self.target];
    [invocation invoke];
}

@end
```

**UPDATE** This bug is fixed on OS X 10.8. According to [OS X Mountain Lion Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html):

> Prior to Mac OS 10.8, -[NSObject autoContentAccessingProxy] returned an object that did not properly implement message forwarding. This proxy now behaves correctly on Mac OS 10.8.

So you need to compile the above code only if you are targeting OS X 10.7 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, `-autoContentAccessingProxy` is totally broken. `NSAutoContentAccessingProxy` is a subclass of `NSProxy` and should therefore implement the `methodSignatureForSelector:` and `forwardInvocation:` methods or the `forwardingTargetForSelector:` method if running on iOS 4 or greater.

Here is a hardcore way of fixing the `NSAutoContentAccessingProxy` class by adding the `methodSignatureForSelector:` and `forwardInvocation:` methods at runtime. Just add the following to your project (do not compile this with ARC).

```
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <mach-o/nlist.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void FixAutoContentAccessingProxy(void);
static id _target(id autoContentAccessingProxy);
static NSMethodSignature *NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_methodSignatureForSelector(id self, SEL _cmd, SEL selector);
static void NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_forwardInvocation(id self, SEL _cmd, NSInvocation *invocation);

__attribute__((constructor)) void FixAutoContentAccessingProxy(void)
{
    Class NSAutoContentAccessingProxy = objc_lookUpClass("NSAutoContentAccessingProxy");
    Method methodSignatureForSelector = class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], @selector(methodSignatureForSelector:));
    Method forwardInvocation = class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], @selector(forwardInvocation:));
    class_addMethod(NSAutoContentAccessingProxy, @selector(methodSignatureForSelector:), (IMP)NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_methodSignatureForSelector, method_getTypeEncoding(methodSignatureForSelector));
    class_addMethod(NSAutoContentAccessingProxy, @selector(forwardInvocation:), (IMP)NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_forwardInvocation, method_getTypeEncoding(forwardInvocation));
}

static id _target(id autoContentAccessingProxy)
{
    static uint32_t targetIvarOffset;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        struct nlist symlist[] = {{"_OBJC_IVAR_$_NSAutoContentAccessingProxy._target", 0, 0, 0, 0}, NULL};
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
        {
            if (nlist(_dyld_get_image_name(i), symlist) == 0 && symlist[0].n_value != 0)
            {
                uint32_t *_OBJC_IVAR_NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_target = (uint32_t*)((uint32_t)_dyld_get_image_header(i) + symlist[0].n_value);
                targetIvarOffset = *_OBJC_IVAR_NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_target;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return *(id*)((uint32_t)autoContentAccessingProxy + targetIvarOffset);
}

static NSMethodSignature *NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_methodSignatureForSelector(id self, SEL _cmd, SEL selector)
{
    return [_target(self) methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
}

static void NSAutoContentAccessingProxy_forwardInvocation(id self, SEL _cmd, NSInvocation *invocation)
{
    [invocation setTarget:_target(self)];
    [invocation invoke];
}
```

This workaround should be used only to demonstrate how `NSAutoContentAccessingProxy` is broken. Anyway this will only work on the simulator because the `nlist` call will fail on the device. You could actually make it work on the device by using `APEFindSymbol` from [APELite-arm](https://github.com/0xced/APELite-arm/blob/master/MobileSubstrateAPELite.cpp) instead of `nlist` but I don't recommend it.

You should definitely [file a bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com) about it to Apple.